# key shortcut to cycle between two windows in vim

Tags: vim

Is there an easy way to cycle between two windows (buffers!) in vim?
With `vim file1 file2` one can use `:n` and `:N` to go back and forth. But this is cumbersome, leads to errors if either `:n` or `:N` is typed twice.

I'm hoping for something simple as `ZZ` to go back and forth with a single key.

Comment: After the 1st `:n` you can use [`CTRL-^`](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#CTRL-^). BTW after `vim file1 file2` you don't have 2 windows — you have 1 window with 2 buffers (files loaded into memory).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an easy way to cycle between two windows (buffers!)

Well… "windows", "buffers", or, since you are using `:n` and `:N`, "files"? They are not the same thing at all.

### Files

As was mentioned in the comments, `<C-^>` (or `<C-6>` on some keyboards) can be used to switch between two files but, since it relies on the notion of "alternate file", you must do `:next` first in order to establish the relationship between the two files.

The problem with the argument list, the list where the files you passed as argument to Vim are stored, is that it is quite low-level. `:n` and `:N` don't wrap around, the alternate file is not set automatically, etc. Bummer.

Example:

```
$ vim file1 file2    # open two files, file1 is current
:n                   " switch to file2
<C-^>                " switch to file1
<C-^>                " switch to file2
<C-^>                " switch to file1
…
```

See `:help argument-list`.

### Buffers

Every "file" you open in Vim (from within Vim or from the shell) becomes a *buffer* so, in addition to the low-level argument list, you have the buffer list which operates at a slightly higher level.

Since you only opened two files, you only have two buffers, between which you can switch with `:help :bnext` because, unlike `:n` and `:N`, `:bn` (and `:bN`) wrap around.

Example:

```
$ vim file1 file2    # open two files and therefore two buffers, file1 is current
:bn                  " switch to file2
:bn                  " switch to file1
:bn                  " switch to file2
:bn                  " switch to file1
…
```

Note that you can map `:bn` to something easier if you want.

`<C-^>` can also be used in this context because the boundary between "file" and "buffer" is a bit murky, but you still have to establish the relationship first by doing a manual switch.

### Windows

You can switch between two windows with `<C-w>p`: `:help CTRL-W_p`.

### Going forward

`<C-^>` is quite useful but you need to establish a relationship between two files/buffers for it to work and Vim unfortunately doesn't do that at startup. It is possible to force it, though, but it is not exactly intuitive. YMMV:

```
$ vim +n +N file1 file2
```

See `:help -+c`.

Answer (score 0):

I set the following in my ~/.vimrc for this purpose.

```
    """"  Faster buffer cycling """
    nnoremap <C-n> :bnext<CR>
    nnoremap <C-p> :bprev<CR>
```

Doing this sacrifices the `<c-n>` and `<c-p>` native behavior, but those are literally duplicates of the behavior of the `k` and `j` keys.